# How can I serialize / de-serialize a Django QuerySet without executing the queryset?

Tags: django

I noticed that if I pass a queryset to a Celery task (which, therefore, serializes it):

`my_awesome_task.apply_async((my_queryset,), queue='whatever')`

the query is executed, thus pulling all of the objects from the DB and serializing them for nothing.

Is there a way to avoid that and have it just serialize the un-executed QuerySet, itself, leaving the DB pummeling to the Celery task?

Comment: You could pass a sql expression as a string `str(my_queryset.query)` and rebuild the queryset in the task using `manager.raw(sql)`. Never tried it myself, but it might work. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/sql/#django.db.models.Manager.raw

Comment: That's similar to what I've got, so far (I'm just passing `my_queryset.query` in without casting it to a `str`), which seems to work.  I just don't know if there are any gotchas with re-building a QuerySet based solely on the `query` field...  Hoping to see how others might have tackled the problem and if there's something more robust than that.

Comment: It looks like `.query` is what the docs recommend for pickling / unpickling. It also explains the execution (use case is caching): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#pickling-querysets  ...Depending on your use case, you might also be able to do it by passing Q objects and model classes.